# detect deleted word from textarea

Tags: javascript, forms, tags, textarea, submit

I am having difficulty with a form tag at the moment. I have added the ability to add tags to a textarea now which is cool and it works very well. I am now trying to implement a way in which when the tag word from the textarea is deleted it makes the tag button inactive as at the moment when you click the tag it creates and active state with css.

I know that this will require regex but I have no clue to be honest how I would make that work. Any help would be mucho appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

This adds the tags from the taglist into the form textarea:

```
$('#tagList li a').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        var selectedTags = $('#field5').val();
        if (selectedTags === '') {
            selectedTags = $(this).text();
        } else {
            selectedTags += ', ' + $(this).text();
        }
        $('#field5').val(selectedTags);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is what creates the active state on the tag buttons themselves once clicked:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul#tagList li").bind("mousedown",function() {
        $("img", this).css("z-index", "9999999");
        $("img.overlay", this).css("z-index", "999999");              
    });
});
```

Does this help?

Cheers

Comment: Would you care to share some code?

Comment: Hi Daniel, just added the code above.

Comment: 1. Could you show all the code (html too). 
2. Format the code.
3. take a look at this http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple.
4. you should say your using jquery.

Comment: Hi Daniel, really sorry about that, here is the link http://www.markdunbavan.co.uk/betaburo/start

Comment: Hi I would use something like this: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin. if you want to stay with what you have i would prevent editing the the text area directly and only allow using the buttons. clicking an active button would remove it. you could do it with a regex and allow editing of the textarea but it seems the wrong way to go.